# I want to draw the road map when i select the few location using checkbox.

Tags: javascript, php

I want to draw the road map when i select the few location using check boxes in form.php. I post that locations into map.php file, I assign that posted values into $location array and now I want to assign that $location array values into javascript calcRoute() function's waypoints array. How can I do that ?

```
<form action="map.php" method="post">

<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="horton" name="wildlife"> Horton Plains National Park <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="minneriya " name="wildlife"> Minneriya National Parks <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="galoye" name="wildlife"> Galoye National park<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="udawalawa" name="wildlife"> Uda Walawe National Park<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="wasgamuwa" name="wildlife"> Wasgomuwa National Park<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="yala" name="wildlife"> Yala West (Ruhuna) National Park 

</form>


<?php
$location = array();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])){
        foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){
            $location = $selected;   
        }
    }
}
```

?>

```
function calcRoute() {
  var request = {
  origin: 'Colombo',
  destination: 'Colombo',
  waypoints:[{location: 'Kandy'}, {location: 'gampaha'}, {location: 'jaffna'}],  
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
     directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If `calcRoute()` is in `map.php` then you could transform the locations with PHP into a valid JSON string with `$locations_json=json_encode($_POST['check_list']);` and parse that with JavaScript either as a global variable or as a property to some global variable you set up before like

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
...
// somewhere in your code:
var locations=<?= $locations_json ?>;
...
// further JavaScript code
</script>
```

In JavaScript `locations` should now be straight JavaScript Array containing just the names of your checked locations like e.g. `['horton','galoye','yala']`. To get the `waypoints` just do

```
waypoints=locations.map(function(e){return {location:e};});
```

See here for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fo4rt6vL/2/

Comment: I got the locations into java script function via json. but still struggle because of i couldn't include those locations into waypoints array. I kindly appreciate if you can Please explain more.. thank you